# Migration from master/slave to HRD and email limited to 100/day

Tags: google-app-engine

Almost a week ago I migrated my (paid) app from Master/Slave to HRD. Since that time my app has been restricted to 100 emails/day with a warning indicating "Resource is currently experiencing a short-term quota limit". I know it mentions a limitation until the first successful billing so I was hoping the limit would disappear once that happened - but alas it has not! I have also filled out the "request additional resources" form hoping that might help.

Anyone encountered this problem migrating from master/slave? Any suggestions of who I can contact or how I can recover from this limit? The migration process was relatively smooth - except for this problem which has become a significant impact to my customers.

Comment: Would HUGELY appreciate if someone would at least point me in the right direction of the correct way to get help for Google App Engine problems in general. Is it possible to purchase a support call without migrating your billing to a $500/month plan? It seems like the support choices are NONE or PREMIUM - but is there anything in between those two extremes?

Comment: UPDATE: It appears that the mail limit has now been removed - exactly one week after switching from Master/Slave to HRD. A charge cleared and then the limit removed (the charge that cleared last week appears was actually for zero dollars).

So, the issue with MY application is resolved. However, I find it hard to believe that migrating from a paid Master/Slave to paid HRD results in a one week gap of mail service!

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem right now.  I just finished my HRD migration yesterday and only today realized that my Mail API requests are failing because the mail quota on my new HRD app is only at 100 messages per day.  I did not have this limitation before, and I find it pretty disappointing that such a triviality is causing my users trouble despite a successful migration.  I submitted a quota increase request and hoping I don't also have to wait a week before it's applied.

Anyone who is waiting until the last minute to migrate their app to HRD be warned: make sure you apply for a mail quota increase on your new app because your old setting will not carry over, even if you have billing enabled on both apps.